# Is there any error in my solution?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ is continuous function for all real values of $x$ and satisfies $$\int^x_0  f(t)dt =\int^1_{x} t^2f(t)dt +\frac{x^{16}}{8}+\frac{x^6}{3}+a$$

Then the value of a is equal to:

(a)  $\frac{-167}{840}$

(b) $\frac{-167}{840}$

(c) $\frac{-167}{840}$

(d) $\frac{-167}{840}$

Is there any error in my following solution:

For $x =1$, $$\int^1_0 f(1)dt =0+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{3}+a = \frac{11}{24}+a$$

Differentiating both sides

$$f(x) = -x^2f(x) +2x^{15}+2x^5$$

$$\implies 2 \int^1_0 \frac{x^{15}+x^5}{1+x^2}dx =\frac{11}{24}+a$$

$$\implies a =-\frac{167}{840}$$

Comment: What is the source of your questions ?

Comment: how do (a), (b), (c), (d) differ?

Comment: When you plugged in $x=1,$ the integral should become $\int_0^1f(t)dt$ (That is a constant, so its derivative is zero at your differentiate both sides step.)

Comment: yes about what the integral should become, but the differentiation apparently involves the equation of the second line of the question FTC @coffeemath sultan http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+(x^15+x^6)/(1+x^2)

Comment: @Mirko You're right, and the OP equation starting $f(x)=$ is the correct application of FTC.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are doing, although differentiating to find $f$ is the right way to go:

$$f(x) = -x^2 f(x) + 2 x^{15} + 2 x^5 \implies f(x) = 2 x^5 \frac{1+x^{10}}{1+x^2} = 2 x^5 (1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8)$$

Now plug in $x=0$ in the integral equation to find that

$$a = -2 \int_0^1 dx \,(x^7-x^9+x^{11}-x^{13}+x^{15}) = - \left (\frac14-\frac15+\frac16-\frac17+\frac18\ \right ) = -\frac{167}{840}$$